# How to select DOM element by its index

Tags: jquery

i have slider with nav buttons, and i want to show correct image when user hovers button (slide). So i take number of hovered button by index()

```
var slideNr = $('.slidermenu li').index($('.activeslide'));
```

I checked the value and this works fine. My problem starts when i want to add class (show the correct image) "activeimg" to the img with same index as the button.

```
$('.sliderimage :eq(slideNr)').addClass("activeimg");
```

I tried :eq and :get, both didint want work, any ideas?

Edit:

HTML

```
<div class="sliderimage">
<img src="img.jpg">
<img src="imga.jpg">
<img src="imgb.jpg">
<img src="imgd.jpg">
<img src="imgc.jpg">
</div>

<div class="slidermenu">
          <ul>
            <li>button1</li>
            <li>button2</li>
            <li>button3</li>
            <li>button4</li>
            <li>button5</li>
          </ul>
```

JS

```
    $(".slidermenu li").hover(

    function () {
        clearInterval(timer);
            $('.slidermenu ul :not(this)').removeClass("activeslide");
            $(this).addClass("activeslide");
            var slideNr = $('.slidermenu li').index($('.activeslide'));
 ----problem-------------
            $('.sliderimage img :not(:eq(slideNr))').removeClass("activeimg");
            $('.sliderimage :eq(slideNr)').addClass("activeimg");
 -----------------
    },
    function () {
        timer = setInterval( slidedown, 3000);
    }
```

Comment: Not enough code shown to see how those snippets are used or what html they reference

Comment: You need to show enough HTML, and JavaScript/jQuery to reproduce your problem (see the "[MCVE]" guidelines).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer to use the eq function instead.
According to the jQuery documentation:

> Given a jQuery object that represents a set of DOM elements, the .eq() method constructs a new jQuery object from one element within that set. The supplied index identifies the position of this element in the set.

```
$('.sliderimage').eq(slideNr).addClass("activeimg");
```

Comment: i screw up selector too, $('.sliderimage img').eq(slideNr).addClass("activeimg"); works ty!

Answer (score 1):

You are using 'slideNr' as a **string**, not as **variable**.

Try this:

```
$('.sliderimage :eq('+slideNr+')').addClass("activeimg");
```